# how to hide datagrid column

Tags: asp.net

I have one data grid,I want to Hide last entire column of data grid
How to do this...
Iam using Asp.net1.1

Answer (score 1):

```
YourGridView1.Columns[LastColumnIndex].Visible = false;
```

LastColumnIndex should be the index of the last column